# Whats the way to use Zend_Acl in View to show/hide parts of view

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl, zend-controller-plugin

I am wondering whats the way to use Zend_Acl to show/hide parts of view? I am thinking I will

1. Create a Controller Plugin that passes the logged in user + acl to view

   ```
    $this->view->loggedInUser = Zend_Auth::getIdentity();
    $this->view->acl = Zend_Registry::get('acl');
   ```
2. Then in view scripts do something like

   ```
   $this->acl->isAllowed($this->view->loggedInUser, 'resource', 'privilege');
   ```

Or is there a better way? Or should I use a View Helper? That returns a boolean whether the logged in user is allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using it in the view, so for me ViewHelper is correct place for that - I've done it once that way:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_HasAccess extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    private $_acl;
    public function hasAccess($role, $controller, $action)
    {
        if (!$this->_acl) {
            $this->_acl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getPlugin('Acl'); 
            //In yout case registry, but front controller plugin is better way to implement ACL
        }
        return $this->_acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action);
    }
}
```